# How to clear break point error on windows phone using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar

Tags: .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml-toolkit

HI all I am developing a calendar application for windows phone and I am decided to use WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar,and I just opened a new project and add WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar reference then create calendar in xaml,That is it ,It s build successfully, But when I loaded it throws a exception in XamlTypeInfo.g.cs as

"An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Calendar.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'WinRTXamlToolkit, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."

How can I overcome it friends...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed it and it worked "fine", but it is possible it has been fixed since 1.7.0.0.
I just got the NuGet package version 1.7.2.0 from http://www.nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit.Controls.Calendar.WindowsPhone and put this in my page.

```
<Page
    x:Class="App6.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App6"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid>
        <Viewbox>
            <controls:Calendar />
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

This is what I see:

[image]

Comment: Im having the same issue with 1.7.2.0 version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949193/winrt-xamltoolkit-calendar-control

Comment: Seems like there is a bug indeed. You have to also install WinRT XAML Toolkit for Windows Phone 8.1 or wait for next version. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949193/winrt-xamltoolkit-calendar-control/25951918#25951918